# install fails in make v8

Tags: makefile, installation, v8

I became error on installing v8:

make:

```
# make library=shared i18nsupport=off native
PYTHONPATH="/tmp/v8/tools/generate_shim_headers:/tmp/v8/build::/tmp/v8/build/gyp/pylib:" \
        GYP_GENERATORS=make \
        build/gyp/gyp --generator-output="out" build/all.gyp \
                      -Ibuild/standalone.gypi --depth=. -S.native  -Dcomponent=shared_library -Dv8_enable_backtrace=1 -Dv8_enable_i18n_support=0 -Darm_fpu=default -Darm_float_abi=default
make[1]: Entering directory `/tmp/v8/out'
  CXX(target) /tmp/v8/out/native/obj.target/v8_base/src/accessors.o
/tmp/v8/third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/clang++: 1: /tmp/v8/third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/clang++: Syntax error: ")" unexpected
make[1]: *** [/tmp/v8/out/native/obj.target/v8_base/src/accessors.o] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/v8/out'
make: *** [native] Error 2
```

Comment: What does `file /tmp/v8/third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/clang++` say?

Comment: Sorry - binary data.

Answer (score 0):

I think this (exceedingly non-helpful ☹) error message is what you get when you try to run the bundled clang (which is an x86_64 binary) on a 32-bit system. Try `GYPFLAGs="-Dclang=0"` to fall back to your system's default compiler:

```
make library=shared i18nsupport=off native GYPFLAGS="-Dclang=0"
```